# GeoPandas dataFrame using iterrows() to fill a dictionary with column data

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, geopandas

I am using pandas DataFrame to make a nested dictionary with a column that contains names. Each dictionary element is a nested dictionary and each nested dictionary's key is a name from the DataFrame column.

I am using this line to fill the dictionary:

```
for row, name in map_datafile.iterrows():         
    material_count[name._get_value(label='NAME')] = {}
```

For some reason, the resulting dictionary contains only 579 of the 586 names contained in the DataFrame. For this reason, when I go to add a column with new data that I calculated from this dictionary, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Indicating that the length of the values to be inserted into the DataFrame is different than the DataFrame.

Am I filling the dictionary incorrectly? Any advice on this issue would be great, I am new to DataFrames.

Answer (score 0):

`.iterrows()` returns the index then the row.
Also, you can access the value with a different syntax in place of calling `._get_value()`.
So you can do instead:

```
for idx, row in map_datafile.iterrows():         
    material_count[row['NAME']] = {}
```

You could alternatively do (probably faster):

```
material_count = {k:{} for k in map_datafile['NAME'].to_list()}
```